# db2 union, return zero if null

Tags: sql, db2

This unioned query works perfectly but there are some instances where there are no records for one of the three conditions.

All I would like to do is make it so that this at least returns a value of '0' if no records are found.

In other words, if nothing is found for PRIOR, instead of returning

```
123 | Current | 1
123 | Full    | 2
```

I would get

```
123 | PRIOR   | 0
123 | Current | 1
123 | Full    | 2
```

QUERY:

```
select ID, 'PRIOR' as Range, count(*) as count
    from table1
where ID = 123
AND date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-04-13'
group by ID
union all
select ID, 'CURRENT' as Range, count(*) as count
    from table1
where ID = 123
AND date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-04-13'
group by ID
union ALL
select ID, 'FULL' as Range, count(*) as count
    from table1
where ID = 123
AND date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
group by ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may rephrase your query to use conditional aggregation with no `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    ID, 'PRIOR' AS Range,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-04-13' AND ID = 123
               THEN 1 END) AS count
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ID, 'CURRENT' AS Range,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-04-13' AND ID = 123
               THEN 1 END) AS count
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ID, 'FULL' AS Range,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31' AND ID = 123
               THEN 1 END) AS count
FROM table1;
```

The reason the above version should get around your problem is that it guarantees that a count report will happen for each subquery in the union, as each subquery covers the entire table.  The only requirement now is that `table1` exists.  In your original version, there would need to be at least one record with an `ID` of `123`, otherwise no records would be returned.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense logically, thank you! Works great

Answer (score 1):

How about putting the values in a single row?

```
select ID,
       sum(case when date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-04-13' then 1 else 0 end) as prior,
       sum(case when date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-04-13' then 1 else 0 end) as current,
       sum(case when date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) as full
from table1
where ID = 123
group by ID;
```

Personally, I would find the data on a single row easier to work with.